# Java: bind and connect methods

Tags: java, udp, bind, connect, nat

What is the main purpose of bind and connect methods in a datagram socket? Are they necessary to use? Does the usage of these methods have any relation with the entries in a router for incoming and outgoing packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the main purpose of bind and connect methods in a datagram socket?

`bind()` binds the socket to a local interface and port. `connect()` conditions the local UDP stack to only send to and receive from the connect target, as far as that socket is concerned.

> Are they necessary to use?

It is only necessary to use `bind()` if you need to use a specific local port so that peers who are expecting to send to that port can succeed. It is only necessary to use `connect()` if you are only interested in one peer and want all other UDP activity filtered out automatically.

> Does the usage of these methods have any relation with the entries in a router for incoming and outgoing packets?

If you don't call `bind(),` the first time you send any data anywhere an automatic `bind()` will take place to the IP address indicated as the best local route to the target by the unicast IP routing tables.